# validate user input in comboBox using RegExpValidator in Flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex, combobox, validation

i try to do the above by specifying a RegExpValidator like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RegExpValidator id="regExpV"
                        source="{zoomCB}"  property="textInput"
                        expression="^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])\%?$"
                        invalid = "validateZoomValue(event);"
                        valid = "validateZoomValue(event);"
                        trigger="{zoomCB}"
                        triggerEvent="change"/> 

</fx:Declarations>
```

for the combobox:

`<s:ComboBox id="zoomCB" width="60" maxChars="3" />`

but the function to validate

```
private function validateZoomValue(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
{
            if(event.type == "valid")
            {
                Alert.show("Valid");
            }
            else
            {
                Alert.show("Invalid");
            }
}
```

always throws invalid although the string given at input is ok! the problem is that the property to check should be the text property of textInput but how can i specify that?
I tried putting as a source="{zoomCB.textInput}" and property="text" but it could not bind to zoomCB.textInput!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problem here.

1. Remove trigger property from RegExpValidator which require either source or trigger property not both at a time.
2. In declaration block zoomCB.textInput here textInput not yet created so you can't use in binding expression.

   ```
   <mx:RegExpValidator id="regExpV"
                       property="textInput"
                       expression="^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])\%?$"
                       invalid = "validateZoomValue(event);"
                       valid = "validateZoomValue(event);"
                       triggerEvent="change"/>
   ```

To bind the textInput to RegExpValidator Component use creation complete event.

```
<s:ComboBox id="zoomCB" width="60" maxChars="3" creationComplete="{regExpV.source = zoomCB.textInput}"/>
```

This will works fine.

Comment: it works fine except that the property="textInput" should be replaced by property="text" in order to take changes of the text of textInput.